# What is the relation between zeta and cut-off regularization of the Casimir effect?

Tags: regularization, casimir-effect

In the literature there are at least two methods to derive Casimir effect:

- original one by Casimir himself: take the quantized energy between plates minus the free space energy, then regularize, e.g. by cut-off function and use Euler-Maclaurin formula
- modern one: take the quantized energy between plates, regularize it by zeta and analyticaly continue to physical value

Obviously the results are the same.

Two remarks:

- "(...) This suggests an important physical intuition for zeta renormalization: using the analytic continuation from s=3 to s=0 in some sense corresponds to subtracting the electromagnetic field's inherent contribution to the ground state energy. In Casimir's derivation we removed the infnite contribution of the field by taking the difference of two configurations, in effect subtracting whatever (infnite) energy the field possesses in free space. Here the subtraction may not be as intuitive, but its analytic simplicity makes it a powerful tool for analyzing vacuum energy problems." (https://aphyr.com/data/journals/113/comps.pdf, pg.13)
- the post http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/ explains what is the relation between cut-off and zeta, but still in two derivations above we have two different objects to regularize!

**My question is: how this difference, i.e. neglecting the free space energy in the latter approach, is explained from the physical point of view?** (perhaps one could elaborate on first remark)

Comment: Aren't you glad that two kinds of intellectual nonsense agree with each other? That calls for a beer... but not necessarily for the celebration of a deep understanding of the physical vacuum... I am not trying to be unkind here. Bohr's model of atoms could explain a few things correctly, but that was luck. I would think of the current state of QFT with regards to the self-energy of the vacuum in very much the same way. We can make a few lucky guesses, but that's probably it. I would be glad to hear if someone could correct my ignorance on the matter, though.

Comment: @CuriousOne: well, it would be interesting if the result was only a coincidence, especially the effect being connected to van der Waals force. Still this difference in two approaches is obscure.

Comment: First link is dead now. Archived by the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20210120213457/https://aphyr.com/data/journals/113/comps.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in the draft by Kleinert: http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/qft.pdf, pg. 600.

The fact that is not mentioned in other sources - the free space energy (aka zero-point energy) that we subtract in the original approach, goes to $0$ after analytic continuation performed as in the second (zeta regularization) approach (it can be shown using dimensional regularization).

In other words, the *difference* between the quantized energy between plates and the free space energy should always be taken in order to obtain Casimir effect (at least we don't want to use van der Waals forces), and this is physically reasonable. It is just specific to zeta regularization that the free space energy goes to $0$, thus often not even mentioned (!) in other texts.

Comment: The link is dead now. Archived by the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150623011722/http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b6/psfiles/qft.pdf